# Trouble connecting controller using routing in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, controller, routes, ng-show, ng-hide

Ill try and do my best to explain...

It doesn't seem like my controller is connecting/working properly. I'm not sure exactly why, every time I check my syntax seems correct. Here is my route declaration:

```
angular.module('portfolio', ['ngRoute']).config(function ($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
    $routeProvider.when('/', {
        templateUrl: '/public/app/views/main.html',
        controller: 'MainCtrl', 
        controllerAs: 'main'
    }).when('/about', {
        templateUrl: '/public/app/views/about.html',
        controller: 'AboutCtrl',
        controllerAs: 'about'
    }).when('/Resume', {
        templateUrl: '/public/app/views/resume.html', 
        controller: 'ResumeCtrl',
        controllerAs: 'Resume'
    }).when('/Samples', {
        templateUrl: '/public/app/views/samples.html', 
        controller: 'SamplesCtrl',
        controllerAs: 'Samples'
    }).otherwise({
        redirectTo: '/'
    });
    $locationProvider.html5Mode(false).hashPrefix('');
});
```

Just as an example here is my resume view:

```
<paper-button ng-click="changeEx()" raised>Experience</paper-button>
<paper-button ng-click="changeSkills()" raised>Skills</paper-button>
<paper-button ng-click="changeEdu()" raised>Education</paper-button>
<paper-button ng-click="changeMisc()" raised>Misc.</paper-button>
<div ng-hide="exp">
    <p>Experience</p>
</div>
<div ng-show="skills">
    <p>Skills</p>
</div>
<div ng-show="education">
    <p>Education</p>
</div>
<div ng-show="misc">
    <p>Misc.</p>
</div>
```

Finally, here is the declaration of the controller for the resume view:

```
angular.module('portfolio', []).controller('ResumeCtrl', function () {
    this.exp = true;
});
```

Obviously, this controller is incomplete but I am simply trying to test it by using this variable.

Comment: Remove the brackets from the controller declaration, otherwise you are redefining the portfolio app.  So:  `angular.module('portfolio').controller...`

Comment: You also did not describe the problem you are having. "Not working" does not tell us much. Be specific. What is not working?

Comment: Sorry, I should have been more specific. The div is not hiding. View switching works fine however the controllers never seen to apply. I tried removing the bracket and using both $scope and your other suggestion but I am still having the same problem. Could it be because I am testing in brackets? I had to step away but will be posting a fire base copy of the page later maybe that will help

Answer (score 1):

Do not use square brackets when you are referencing a module that has already been declared. This is interpreted by Angular as declaring a new module:

```
angular.module('portfolio').controller('ResumeCtrl', function () {
    this.exp = true;
});
```

The next thing I would check is your main HTML page. Do you have this directive somewhere on your page:

```
<div ng-view></div>
```

Another problem is that you are declaring `controllerAs` in your route as `Resume`, but you are using `this.exp` to assign your variable and also trying to reference `exp` in your view. You need to follow this pattern instead, or use `$scope`:

```
angular.module('portfolio').controller('ResumeCtrl', function () {
  var Resume = this;
  Resume.exp = true;
});
```

And in your view you should reference the variable using the same name you defined in `controllerAs`:

```
<div ng-hide="Resume.exp">
  <p>Experience</p>
</div>
```

Or, alternatively, you can keep your view the same, but assign your variable using `$scope`:

```
angular.module('portfolio').controller('ResumeCtrl', function ($scope) {
  $scope.exp = true;
});
```

Comment: Thanks again, even after taking your suggestions I still seem to have the same problem. The divs do not seem to respond to directives like ng-show. On top of it firebase does not seem to want to deploy either my views or controllers directory, so I can not show you.